# GROUP BY multiple derived Max() and Min() columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, max

I am trying to create a script that will group a tables contents by a series of columns that I have taken `MAX()` of.

It difficult to describe without the scenario:

I have a table of bookings which I have to create a table from of single customer, the customers are split down by res system, each res system requires a different grouping using different columns.

I.E:

```
277000 bookings for Ipcos
289300 bookings for Daph
300000 bookings for Tard
```

They are all stored in same table and I want to take the max of all columns except a couple which I have to cast into integers and sum() other columns up.

My problem comes when I have to group by the casted value I have created and the `Min()` value I have created.

I tried joining table onto each other but that didn't work, can someone point me in the right direction please as getting very frustrated.

Code for selecting Ipcos

```
SELECT
    SUM(CAST(TotalCost AS MONEY)) AS TotalCost, 
    NettCost = Null,    
    Paid = Null,    
    Balance = Null, 
    Discount = Null,    
    Commission = Null,  
    Max(Adults) AS Adults,  
    Max(Children)AS Children,
    Max(Infants) AS Infants,
    Max(PAX) AS PAX,
    Sum(CAST(Duration AS int)) AS Duration,
    MAX([IdentityValue]) AS IdentityValue,
    MAX([FileName]) AS FileName,
    MAX([SheetName]) AS SheetName,
    MAX([LineNum]) AS LineNum,
    MAX([BookingDate]) AS BookingDate,
    CAST([DepartureDate] AS Int) AS IntDepartureDate,
    CAST([BookingDate] AS int) AS IntBookingDate,
    MIN(LineNum) AS MinLineNum
FROM 
    Booking
WHERE ResID = 3
GROUP BY 
    MinLineNum, IntBookingDate, IntDepartureDate
```

the other systems are very similar to this

any help would be fantastic cheers in adavnce

Comment: you can not use columns in Group by statements which are used as alias in select statement,  try using the actual column names like 

Group By LineNum, BookingDate, DepartureDate 

Also you want to aggregate LineNum grouping on LineNum,  that does not sound correct, please check

Comment: group by [DepartureDate], [BookingDate]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the over ( partition by ) statement in order tou group by different columns. Look here [Over clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)